# Webhost Whitelist (C++)

Tags: c++

I have no idea how to go about doing this... absolutely none.

Here's what I'm aiming for:

Right now, I have a very simple login whitelist. Here's the code:

```
string username;
cout << "Username: ";
cin >> username
if (username == "test" or "username" or "whitelist") {
// my code
}
```

This works, but I'm constantly updating it, and I'd rather keep the usernames on a webhost.

Sorry if I did the above code wrong, I'm very new to C++ and just trying to learn a few things at a time.

Thanks!

Comment: First, make a description in human language (pseudo code). Then, translate it to C++. It's neither clear what you want nor is it clear how the above doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe you should put the whitelist into a textfile and parse that file during your verification. Or maybe you would prefer using a database, but this one is more complex.

Comment: "Here is the code [...] it works" - are you sure it is working to begin with? That string comparison line looks decidedly iffy. I bet it returns `true` for **all** text you enter.

Answer (score 0):

BTW, a correction on syntax:

```
if ((username == "test") or (username == "username) or (username == "whitelist"))
```

With that out of the way...

Essentially you are searching a container of strings for a given string.  The container selection is yours, but a few include: `std::vector`, `std::list` and `std::set`.

I suggest you initialize your "whitelist" container and then search the container.  With a sorted container, you may be able to use more efficient search functions such as `binary_search` or `lower_bound`.

You may want to consider using a database.

Comment: Okay, here's what I want to do.

I have a notepad file in dropbox and I'd like to make it so that I can enter in usernames and passwords into it and let them log in with a specific one

Example for the text file:

test
test

username
password